# How to use tooltips with two overlapped x-axes in Chart JS?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a bar chart where weekly information is shown in an x-axis, the labels correspond to the current day (rightmost label) going back 1 week each (12/28, 12/21, etc). In the same chart there is another scale/x-axis with (different) daily information. When clicking on each day's bar, a tooltip appears with the information for that day.

[Example of tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBB0E.png)

The problem is that when clicking on one of the days where weekly + daily cross over, the weekly index is used so the daily data is displaying information for a different date (ex: for the eighth week bar date is 12/28, but daily information is for the eighth date 11/10).

I tried changing the order of the axes when declaring the chart options, but that messes up the display. I'm looking for a way to access the second axis index instead of defaulting to the top one.